# displaying which questions missed in array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, pass-by-value

I want my program to display which questions missed between two arrays. I would enter all the correct answers for the first 12 then the last 3 I enter wrong. Whenever I try to display it, it comes up with some weird return answer, I think it might be the memory address. I've tried everything I could to get it to print out the question numbers missed. Please any help at all would be extremely appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner

public class DriverTestBlah {
 public static void main(String [] args){

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  char[] correctAnswers = {'A','D','C','A','A','D','B',
    'A','C','A','D','C','B','A','B'};
  char[] userAnswer = new char[correctAnswers.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) //print question numbers/takes user input
      {
      System.out.print("Question " + (i + 1) + ":");
          userAnswer [i] = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
      }//end of for loop
  for(int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) //for loop prints you missed
    {
     System.out.print("You missed question: ");
        for(int y = 0; y < 1; y++) //for loop only takes one question # at a time
          {
           System.out.println(" " + which_questions_missed(userAnswer, correctAnswers));

          }//end of question number for loop
    }//end of 
  }//end of main
//create new class that determines which questions missed and returns their numbers
  public static int []which_questions_missed(char[] userAnswer, char[] correctAnswers){
     int missed[] = new int[correctAnswers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++){
           if (userAnswer[i] != correctAnswers[i]){
             missed[i]=(i+1);//chooses the index of the missed answers and adds 1 to display
            }
        }
     return missed;
  }
 }//end of class
```

Comment: You are trying to print an array. You need `Arrays.toString(which_questions_missed(userAnswer, correctAnswers))`. However, your algorithm looks a bit weird. You may not be getting the results you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the **method** (not a **class**) `which_questions_missed` like this. Notice how I changed the name from `which_questions_missed` to `whichQuestionsMissed` this is no accident use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) not [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) in Java programs:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] correctAnswers = {'A','D','C','A','A','D','B', 'A','C','A','D','C','B','A','B'};
    char[] userAnswer = new char[correctAnswers.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      System.out.print("Question " + (i + 1) + ":");
      userAnswer[i] = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    }
    whichQuestionsMissed(userAnswer, correctAnswers);
  }

  public static void whichQuestionsMissed(char[] userAnswer, char[] correctAnswers) {
    for(int i = 0; i < userAnswer.length; i++) {
      if(Character.toUpperCase(userAnswer[i]) != correctAnswers[i]) {
        System.out.println("You missed question: " + i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It utilizes [`Character.toUpperCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)) which allows the user to enter the equivalent lowercase letters as well.

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FgVL/1)